# How to differentiate Redis-Based Tomcat Session Management in prod and devo

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat8, reddison

I am using redisson's Tomcat Session Manager which allows me to store sessions of Apache Tomcat in Redis. I have hardcoded the link in redis conf file and referenced that file in context.xml in meta INF (path : webapplication/project_name/WebContent/META-INF/context.xml ).

context.xml:

```
<Manager className="org.redisson.tomcat.RedissonSessionManager"
configPath="${catalina.base}/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/redisson.conf" 
readMode="REDIS" updateMode="DEFAULT" broadcastSessionEvents="false"/>
```

redisson.conf:

```
singleServerConfig:
  address: "redis://tomcat-session-store.XXXXX"
  #devo address: "redis://tomcat-session-store.XXXXX"
  # address: "redis://localhost:6379"
  # idleConnectionTimeout: 10000
  # connectTimeout: 10000
  # timeout: 3000
  # retryAttempts: 1
  # retryInterval: 1500
  # password: null
  # subscriptionsPerConnection: 5
  # clientName: null
  # subscriptionConnectionMinimumIdleSize: 1
  # subscriptionConnectionPoolSize: 50
  # connectionMinimumIdleSize: 24
  # connectionPoolSize: 64
  # database: 0
  #dnsMonitoringInterval: 5000
# threads: 16
# nettyThreads: 32
# codec: !<org.redisson.codec.FstCodec> {}
# transportMode: "NIO"
```

I need a solution to differentiate that link in prod and devo without making manual changes.